# MySql spatial: `ST_Contains(g1,g2) || ST_Touches(g1, g2)` vs `ST_distance(g1,g2)=0`

Tags: mysql, distance, contains, spatial, mysql-spatial

I use mysql spatial functions.

I have to understand if points lies withing multipolygon.Birder must be included.

My expriments showed that `ST_Contains` does not include border of Multipolygon

So for now I have 2 solutions which looks like working:
1. `ST_Contains(g1,g2) || ST_Touches(g1, g2)`
2. `ST_distance(g1,g2)=0`

Are that  solutions equivalent ?

Comment: Do you want to test for "single point inside a geometry or on its border" (otherwise your two conditions are clearly not equivalent)? You can use `st_intersects` for that.

Comment: @Solarflare could you please elaborate?

Comment: I just meant that it looks as if you are trying to test if a point lies on the polygon or on its border, and since the border is excluded in `st_contains`, you seem to add an additional `st_touches`. And it looks as if you are trying to now simplify your expression (by `st_distance`). So *if* that is what you are after, I'd try `st_intersects` (="is there any point where they overlap", which, for a point, checks if the point is inside *or on the border* of the other shape). Not entirely sure though if that is your actual question/problem.

Comment: @Solarflare, You understood my question properly. According the docs st_intersect is inversion of st_contains

Comment: No, it's not the inversion (you can just verify that if contains is true, intersects is also true). But you should just test it, it should (for a point and a polygon) do what (I think) you expect.